# My Magento Site is showing up a random phrase in the navigation links

Tags: magento

I have the following Magento site - [www.comfyfrog.com](http://www.comfyfrog.com/) but cannot seem to find where the random address text is coming from that is in the header.

Can anyone help please?

Kind Regards

Comment: Seems like a footer that is being called again in your header. The `DIV` container of the duplicated footer has class=`d8-cmslinks`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try enabling the template hints in Admin > Settings > Developper to find out which template file or block is outputting the text. It generally helps a lot to understand the structure of the page.